# Cycle of retrofit request from AsyncTask into RxJava

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit, rx-java

How can I change the following code from AsyncTask (from `doInBackground` method) into RxJava?

```
MessageRq rq = new MessageRq();
rq.setId(id);
Call<MessageRs> response = App.getApi().getFirstCommand(rq);
nextLink = getNextUrl(response, rq);
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {   
    response = App.getApi().authorize(nextLink, rq);
    nextLink = getNextUrl(response, rq);
}
```

The `getNextUrl` method looks like this:

```
private String getNextUrl(Call<MessageRs> response, MessageRq rq) throws Exception {
        Response<MessageRs> rs = response.execute();
        rq.setData(...);
        ...
        return rs.body().getLink();
}
```

I replaced `Call<MessageRs>` with `Observable<MessageRs>` and, from what I understand, I need `flatMap`. But I do not understand how to use it correctly...

```
myApi.getFirstCommand(rq)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
       .flatMap(response -> { // How can I transfer here both response and rq?
           // and how to do it exactly 10 times?    
           // maybe after flatMap I should add .forEachWhile(cycle < 10) ?     
           String nextLink = getNextUrl(response, rq);
           myApi.authorize(nextLink, rq);
       })
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(// from what I understand, here I should update UI, right?);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue that you're facing is that `rq` is a mutable object that has to be updated with parameters, etc. Such objects do not really play well with the functional approach in RxJava. That being said, it is still possible to work with the mutable state, but you will have to be careful with parallel updates.

```
myApi.getFirstCommand(rq)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .flatMap(response -> getNextUrlObservable(rq, response), 1 )
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(// from what I understand, here I should update UI, right?);
```

The first change that you need to ensure that this sequence is not done in parallel is the second parameter to `flatMap()`, indicating the maximum number of threads that may be used evaluate the inputs. You could also enforce this by applying `take(1)` to each step.

You cannot directly perform an iteration in the observable chain. It is likely possible to build up an observer chain, constructing the chain on the fly, or using the `compose()` operator.